# ArcCatalog 9.3 (ArcInfo) won't open

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, arccatalog

ArcMap, ArcScene and everything else works fine and opens without a problem. However, ArcCatalog cannot open. Instead a window pops up and says:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library.  Runtime Error!  Program:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Bin\ArcCatalog.  This application has
>   requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please
>   contact the application's support team for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of suggestions offered **[here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14580-Microsoft-Visual-C-Runtime-Library-error-in-ArcCatalog)**.

The one that I would try first is to rename your **normal.gxt** and **ArcCatalog.gx** files in \Documents and Settings\\Application Data (sometimes hidden)\ESRI\ArcCatalog.